# iOS app relaunches automatically when user turn off and on the location services in iPhone settings

Tags: ios, iphone, core-location, cllocationmanager, location-services

I'm using location services in my iOS App, It includes  `SignificantLocationChanges` and `Region monitoring`.

I'm recognising the app relaunch cause by using '`UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey`' in AppDelegate.

Consider the app is terminated. In this case when user turn off and on the location services in iPhone settings as shown in the below pic, My app is getting relaunched.

[image]______________[image]

Is it expected behaviour of iOS Apps that registered with `SingnificantLocationChange` & `RegionMonitoring` or any mistake i'm doing.

Thanks.

Comment: Have not checked this kind of behavior with other apps but generally this should not be the case, Can you check with few other apps for the similar case also why are you using UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey this key any special purpose like are you calling some services etc

Comment: I'm using 'UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey' to determine whether the system relaunches the App because of new location events or user opened the app normally.

Comment: Ok did you try turning off the LaunchOptionsLocationKey and try that again? It might be due to that key which you are using and if that is the actual problem then i believe you need to use some alternate way of doing this

Comment: There is nothing we can modify 'UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey'.
It's just to identify if there is any app relaunch because of new location events when we use SignificantLocationChange or Region monitoring.
It is just an if condition like
if([launchOptions objectForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey"])
in application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in AppDelegate.

Check below URL to know more about 'UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey'.
https://community.estimote.com/hc/en-us/articles/203253193-Launching-notifications-in-iOS-when-the-app-is-killed

Answer (score 2):

Its an expected behavior of iOS. Whenever privacy settings are changed for an app, OS sends a SIGKILL which is not a crash.

You can find the official documentation in this link: http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2012/wwdc_2012_session_pdfs/session_710__privacy_support_in_ios_and_os_x.pdf

Comment: Thanks. So, in this case iOS will wake up the app(even if it's in terminated state) if the user turn off and on the location services in iPhone settings?. Is it mentioned clearly in any official docs?.